# loop through array - create new array from this

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have this array for example:

```
$array = [
  'foodTypes' => [
    'pizza' => '120',
    'burger' => [
      'calorie' => '50',
      'sugar' => '10'
      'prices' => [
        'regular' => '150',
        'discount' => '10'
      ]
    ]
  ]
];
```

i want to create loop through this array and create a new array from this (on the way i will check the value of each key and will make changes if i will need in some cases in the new array).

- important: the array is unknown levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a separated class for that, which you can use for example from "app/Classes/NestedArray.php"

```
<?php

// namespace App\Classes; // DON'T FORGET TO WRITE HERE THE CORRECT NAMESPACE FOR YOU

class NestedArray
{
    protected $result = [];

    protected function doSomethingWith($item) {
        // you can do something with $item which is not an array (string, int, or something else)
        // for example, here we will collect all values which great than 10
        if((int)$item > 10) {
            $this->result[] = (int)$item;
        }
    }

    protected function deepDiveIntoNextLevel(array $array) {
        foreach ($array as $item) {
            if(is_array($item)) {
                return $this->deepDiveIntoNextLevel($item);
            } else {
                $this->doSomethingWith($item);
            }
        }
    }

    public function loop(array $initial_array)
    {
        $this->deepDiveIntoNextLevel($initial_array);

        return $this->result;
    }
}
```

In this example I did something with items which are not an array (assuming string or integer). So for using this class anywhere in your app, you can just make an instance and call that within "loop()" function. Like this:

```
// use App\Classes\NestedArray; // ALSO DON'T FORGET TO USE APPROPRIATE CLASS

$array = [
    'foodTypes' => [
        'pizza' => '120',
        'burger' => [
            'calorie' => '50',
            'sugar' => '10',
            'prices' => [
                'regular' => '150',
                'discount' => '10'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
$nestedArray = new NestedArray();
var_dump($nestedArray->loop($array));
```

In this example I've collected all numbers (numeric strings or integers) into one array, which have value greater than 10